# SharePoint full control permission issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, permissions

user have full control permission for SharePoint site, but he can not access it. he is also in the global log . What would be the problem ?

Comment: Is it a general issue for all users with full control or a specific user?

Comment: specific user !

Comment: Is it new site for users or he was able to access it before and all of sudden it started?

Comment: it is new site that I gave him

Comment: Try to add him in site collection admin group

Comment: Please check the page and if there is any inheritance issue with that specific page or any part in the page. drill down and easily you would be able to isolate this permission issue and would prevent the same in future.